# Javascript not working on some element by id's

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to make 3 lines do something:
line 1 rotate 45deg and some translate
line 1 opacity 0
line 1 rotate -45deg and some translate

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skarchmit/FK499/2/)

```
<a href = "#"><div id = "menu" onclick="menu()">
              <div id = "lineOne">1</div>
              <div id = "lineTwo">1</div>
              <div id = "lineThree">1</div>
              </div>
</a>

function menu()
{
    //Show Differnet Button
    document.getElementById('lineOne').style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(45deg) translate3d(10px,10px,0)";
    document.getElementById('lineTwo').style.opacity = ".3";
    document.getElementById('lineThree').style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(-45deg) translate3d(10,-10px,0)";
}

#lineOne, #lineTwo, #lineThree, #line4, #line5, #line6
{
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 7px !important;
    background: black;
    color: rgba(1,1,1,0) !important;
}
```

My code on JS Fiddle is above, and the only result I am getting is the opacity and the first one rotates and translates. Nothing else. I completely ignores the rest. What can I do?

Comment: Please put your code here, as well as on JSFiddle and try to make it clearer exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/FK499/3/

Comment: @Dalorzo It doesnt rotate lineThree. And as well as lineTwo if I were to add it. What browser did you look it through? I looked at it from Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 I written up above, I want line1 to rotate, line2 to lose opacity, line3 to rotate another way.

Comment: It is not a problem with the id, if you tell it to change line 3 to red, it works.

Comment: @ImagineStudios Yea, everything works except for the transform

Comment: The internet **is not** webkit, please do not use webkit styles to the exclusion of web standards. Instead consider adding a class name to the elements, which holds vendor prefixed styles before **standard** CSS property names and values. Webkit values will not be recognised by other user agents and other browsers will therefore be broken on your site. That won't be the fault of the browser, but the developer who wrote the code. Please use standards and do your users a favour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `px` in your transform.

```
document.getElementById('lineThree')
        .style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(-90deg) translate3d(10px,-10px,0)";
```

`translate3d` requires length units.

Answer (score 4):

There were lots of problems. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FK499/42/

First you needed to tell it to put the js in the `<head>` by setting it to "No wrap - in `<head>`"

Second, your function wasn't closed with a `}`.

Third, you didn't need the anchor tag.

Fourth, you were missing the px in the last transform.

HTML:

```
    <div id = "menu" onclick="menu();">
                <div id = "lineOne">1</div>
                <div id = "lineTwo">1</div>
                <div id = "lineThree">1</div>
    </div>
```

and the js:

```
function menu()
        {
        //Show Differnet Button
        document.getElementById('lineOne').style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(45deg) translate3d(10px,10px,0)";
        document.getElementById('lineTwo').style.opacity = ".3";
        document.getElementById('lineThree').style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(-45deg) translate3d(10px,-10px,0)";
        }
```